# how can I find all numbers dividable by multiple numbers between two numbers

Tags: divisibility

How can I find all numbers dividable by let's say 5,7,13 that are 2007***

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number must also be divisible by the least common multiple of $5,7,13$, which is just their product. Now write $2017{*}{*}{*}=2017000+x$ with $0\le x\le 999$, and compute the remainder of division by $5\cdot7\cdot 13$.